# In order combinations given a string

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to create all possible in order combinations of a word's syllables.

For example, I have the word `overflowing` and I have a list of it's syllables `['o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing']`. I would like the output to show all the possible combinations of combining the syllables to make the word: `[('o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing'), ('o', 'verflow', 'ing'), ('o', 'verflowing'), ('overflowing'), ('over', 'flow', 'ing'), ...]`.

Here is my attempt:

```
syllable_list = ['o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing']
list_length = len(syllable_list)
for x in range(0, list_length):
    for y in range(0, list_length):
        if syllable_list[y:x+1]:
            before = ""
            middle = ""
            after = ""
            if syllable_list[0:y]:
                before = ["".join(syllable_list[0:y])]
            if syllable_list[x+1:]:
                after = ["".join(syllable_list[x+1:])]
            middle = ["".join(syllable_list[y:x+1])]
            print(before, middle, after)
```

The output is:

```
 ['o'] ['verflowing']
 ['over'] ['flowing']
['o'] ['ver'] ['flowing']
 ['overflow'] ['ing']
['o'] ['verflow'] ['ing']
['over'] ['flow'] ['ing']
 ['overflowing']
['o'] ['verflowing']
['over'] ['flowing']
['overflow'] ['ing']
```

All the combinations are there, with some duplicates, and I'm missing the `['o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing']` case. What am I doing wrong? Is there a library that already handles this so I don't have to recreate the wheel?

Comment: Practically speaking, what is the value of something like `('o', 'verflowing')`?

Comment: Have you looked into the `itertools.permutations` function? That might be something to point you in the right direction: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator which combines any two consecutive elements for the next level of recursion:

```py
>>> def generate(parts, start=0):
...     yield parts
...     for i in range(start, len(parts)-1):
...         yield from generate([*parts[:i], parts[i]+parts[i+1], *parts[i+2:]], start=i)
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(generate(['o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing'])))
[['o', 'ver', 'flow', 'ing'],
 ['over', 'flow', 'ing'],
 ['overflow', 'ing'],
 ['overflowing'],
 ['over', 'flowing'],
 ['o', 'verflow', 'ing'],
 ['o', 'verflowing'],
 ['o', 'ver', 'flowing']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined only 3 variables (After, middle, and before) you can't get the output with more than 3 strings.

Your code will always join at least 2 strings.

You need to find another way to do this.